# Vue.JS doesn't read json data

Tags: html, css, vue.js, popup, vuetify.js

So i'm new to Vue JS. I was creating this page where I have a button and on clicking it pops up a chat module. Here's my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Query Management</title>
<style>
.headline {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
}
.chat-area {
/*   border: 1px solid #ccc; */
  background: white;
  height: 50vh;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto 2em auto;
}
.message {
  width: 45%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: .5em;
/*   margin-bottom: .5em; */
  font-size: .8em;
}
.message-out {
  background: #407FFF;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.message-in {
  background: #F1F0F0;
  color: black;
}
.chat-inputs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#person1-input {
  padding: .5em;
}
#person2-input {
  padding: .5em;  
}

  #app {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px 1px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.modal-header,
.modal-footer {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
}

.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  color: #415982;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.modal-footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.btn-close {
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #415982;
  background: transparent;
}

.btn {
  color: white;
  background: #415982;
  border: 1px solid #415982;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.modal-fade-enter,
.modal-fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-fade-enter-active,
.modal-fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
</style>
<script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>
<script>
  if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
  }
</script>
</head>
<body translate="no">
<div id="app">
<button type="button" class="btn" @click="showModal">
?
</button>
<modal v-show="isModalVisible" @close="closeModal" />
</div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="modal">

  <transition name="modal-fade">
    <div class="modal-backdrop" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal" ref="modal">
        <header class="modal-header">
          <slot name="header">
            <h2>
             We're thinking of a good title for this box
            </h2>

            <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-right" @click="close" aria-label="Close modal">
              x
            </button>
          </slot>
        </header>

        <section class="modal-body">
          <slot name="body">
 <section ref="chatArea" class="chat-area">
   <p v-for="message in $parent.messages" class="message" :class="{ 'message-out': message.author === 'you', 'message-in': message.author !== 'support' }">
      {{ message.body }}
    </p>

  </section>
          </slot>
        </section>

        <footer class="modal-footer">
          <slot name="footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-green" @click="close" aria-label="Close modal">
              Close Chat
            </button>
          </slot>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js'></script>
<script id="rendered-js">
      const Modal = {
  name: 'modal',
  template: '#modal',
  methods: {
    close(event) {
      this.$emit('close');
    } } };



new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    modal: Modal 
    },

  data() {
messages: [
      {
        body: 'Welcome to the chat, I\'m Bob!',
        author: 'bob'
      },
      {
        body: 'Thank you Bob',
        author: 'you'
      },
      {
        body: 'You\'re most welcome',
        author: 'bob'
      }
    ]
    return {

      isModalVisible: false 
      };


  },


  methods: {
  sendMessage(direction) {
      if (!this.youMessage && !this.bobMessage) {
        return;
      }
      if (direction === 'out') {
        this.messages.push({ body: this.youMessage, author: 'you' });
        this.youMessage = '';
      } else if (direction === 'in') {
        this.messages.push({ body: this.bobMessage, author: 'support' });
        this.bobMessage = '';
      } else {
        alert('There was an error processing the chat... Please try again later!');
      }
      Vue.nextTick(() => {
        let messageDisplay = this.$refs.chatArea;
        messageDisplay.scrollTop = messageDisplay.scrollHeight;
      });
    },
    showModal() {
      this.isModalVisible = true;

    },
    closeModal() {
      this.isModalVisible = false;
    } } 


    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with this code is, when clicking on the button, the box that pops up is just an empty one. I'm not able to make the chat appear inside the box. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not kept `messages` array inside return in data(), this is the reason it was not showing messages, You can see below:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Query Management</title>
<style>
.headline {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
}
.chat-area {
/*   border: 1px solid #ccc; */
  background: white;
  height: 50vh;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto 2em auto;
}
.message {
  width: 45%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: .5em;
/*   margin-bottom: .5em; */
  font-size: .8em;
}
.message-out {
  background: #407FFF;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
.message-in {
  background: #F1F0F0;
  color: black;
}
.chat-inputs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#person1-input {
  padding: .5em;
}
#person2-input {
  padding: .5em;  
}

  #app {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px 1px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.modal-header,
.modal-footer {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
}

.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  color: #415982;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.modal-footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.btn-close {
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #415982;
  background: transparent;
}

.btn {
  color: white;
  background: #415982;
  border: 1px solid #415982;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.modal-fade-enter,
.modal-fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-fade-enter-active,
.modal-fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
</style>
<script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>
<script>
  if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
  }
</script>
</head>
<body translate="no">
<div id="app">
<button type="button" class="btn" @click="showModal">
?
</button>
<modal v-show="isModalVisible" @close="closeModal" />
</div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="modal">

  <transition name="modal-fade">
    <div class="modal-backdrop" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal" ref="modal">
        <header class="modal-header">
          <slot name="header">
            <h2>
             We're thinking of a good title for this box
            </h2>

            <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-right" @click="close" aria-label="Close modal">
              x
            </button>
          </slot>
        </header>

        <section class="modal-body">
          <slot name="body">
 <section ref="chatArea" class="chat-area">
   <p v-for="message in $parent.messages" class="message" :class="{ 'message-out': message.author === 'you', 'message-in': message.author !== 'support' }">
      {{ message.body }}
    </p>

  </section>
          </slot>
        </section>

        <footer class="modal-footer">
          <slot name="footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-green" @click="close" aria-label="Close modal">
              Close Chat
            </button>
          </slot>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js'></script>
<script id="rendered-js">
      const Modal = {
  name: 'modal',
  template: '#modal',
  methods: {
    close(event) {
      this.$emit('close');
    } } };



new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    modal: Modal 
    },

  data() {

    return {

      isModalVisible: false,
      messages: [
      {
        body: 'Welcome to the chat, I\'m Bob!',
        author: 'bob'
      },
      {
        body: 'Thank you Bob',
        author: 'you'
      },
      {
        body: 'You\'re most welcome',
        author: 'bob'
      }
    ]
      };


  },


  methods: {
  sendMessage(direction) {
      if (!this.youMessage && !this.bobMessage) {
        return;
      }
      if (direction === 'out') {
        this.messages.push({ body: this.youMessage, author: 'you' });
        this.youMessage = '';
      } else if (direction === 'in') {
        this.messages.push({ body: this.bobMessage, author: 'support' });
        this.bobMessage = '';
      } else {
        alert('There was an error processing the chat... Please try again later!');
      }
      Vue.nextTick(() => {
        let messageDisplay = this.$refs.chatArea;
        messageDisplay.scrollTop = messageDisplay.scrollHeight;
      });
    },
    showModal() {
      this.isModalVisible = true;

    },
    closeModal() {
      this.isModalVisible = false;
    } } 


    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```